# What are traditional models used in statistics for prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, svm, predictive-models

I'm a beginning undergraduate researcher in data science. My background is in computer science and my mathematical background is weak.

Currently, I'm doing research on predictive models in criminal forecasting using modern machine learning techniques like boosting, naive bayes, SVM, logistic regression and cluster analysis.

While these algorithms are very cool and interesting, I'm curious to know what the majority of people in other fields use. What are some "traditional" techniques that are used that may not perform as well as the aforementioned techniques above?

Comment: I would classify logistic regression as classical approach rather than machine learning, so that would be one example.

Comment: I wonder whether this question might be "too broad", since the list of predictive models is *very* long... perhaps it would benefit from being narrowed down?

Comment: Uncanny resemblance to Dennis Ritchie.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, "traditional" means older methods that have the same purpose. And that would be **Ordinary Least Squares Linear Regression**([invented in 1805](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#History)), which was created in the age before computer. For machine learning, I think basically it's about determination of parameter values, which means that we want to learn from data what not what the VARIABLES are, but their CONSTANT multipliers.  And in 1805, an amazing mapping tool to locate and catch those constants, called [least squares in $y$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), which can be computed by hands and later became very popular, before the invention of computer.